# Suggest good books/resources about modern CSS and design practices

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-experience

Ideally it would be kept up-to date continuously.

Some kind of CSS & Design weekly is another bonus.

The problems I want to solve for myself are:

1. **Understand deeply** all the tricks with CSS (not just how to style with a random snippet from the Internet).
2. **Keep up** with the updates (Chrome is updated regularly, Firefox is, even the ugly brother IE starts doing it).
3. Connect the **UX and the front-end** dev. "Use the cool hack" when it is needed and don't when it's not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read through this if you want to know a ton about CSS

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css

This is a great site, for past reference and future updates:

http://css-tricks.com/

You would also do well to follow nettuts

http://net.tutsplus.com/category/tutorials/html-css-techniques/

If you want to read some books, I recommend highly anything from O'Reilly

http://oreilly.com/css-html/index.html

Comment: +1 I second all these resources, and I'd add some of the stuff from http://www.alistapart.com/ and http://www.abookapart.com/

Comment: I like stuff from A Book Apart. Just before posting the question I purchased a book from them.

Comment: Jason, I read sometimes SitePoint. But the reference if often meaningless. It's like reading RFC out of context. Although it is useful resource sometimes.

The tutsplus is interesting. Thanks for that.

Comment: I like this list and would add http://www.csszengarden.com/ for some really cool examples.